# sql select from table then compare with other table in one statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have to tables in one database.

1. `users`
2. `user_activate`

I have to variables in php

1. `$username = foo;`
2. `$key = jas823k123ksd34324;`

Now I want to select from the table `users` the attribute `user_id` where `user_username == $username`

I do this with this statement

```
$sql = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $user_id = $row['user_id'];
}
```

Now I want to select from the table `user_activate` the attribute `user_activate_key` where `user_activate_key == $key;`

For this I use this statement:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT user_activate_key FROM user_activate WHERE user_activate_key = '$key'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($db, $sql2);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $user_key = row['user_activate_key'];
}
```

Can I do both statements in one statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've written it, two seperate queries is the correct way to do it.  But  I suspect that there's some kind of relationship between `users` and `user_activate` that might make what you're asking for make sense.  Assuming that a `user_activate_key` is tied to a specific `user_id`, you could do something like the following:

```
select users.user_id, ua.user_activate_key
from users u
left join user_activate ua
    on u.user_id = ua.user_id
    and ua.user_activate_key = '$key'
where u.username = '$username'
```

The `LEFT JOIN` means that the user will be shown even if there isn't a matching `user_activate_key` record.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I thought with two queries isnt it that good.